python - generate music from text
please, give me some suggestions
To explain, I type "Sleep Music For Deep Sleep" and it will return a wav file as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wAdQhFJy54 or I give a wav file, it will return the same
Now here is what I have tried:

https://github.com/facebookresearch/audiocraft but it has a Low Quality
  import torchaudio
  from audiocraft.models import MusicGen

  au_crmode = MusicGen.get_pretrained(pre, cache_dir=pret_loca)
  au_crmode.set_generation_params(duration=kwargs['thoigian'])

  melody, sr = torchaudio.load('./176_183.wav')
  # generates using the melody from the given audio and the provided descriptions.
  wav = au_crmode.generate_with_chroma(input_text, melody[None].expand(3, -1, -1), sr)

  for idx, one_wav in enumerate(wav):
       audio_write(f'{idx}', one_wav.cpu(), au_crmode.sample_rate, strategy="loudness")



or
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(pretra[0], cache_dir=pret_loca)
model = MusicgenForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(pretra[0], cache_dir=pret_loca)

sample_length = 30
num_tokens = sample_length * model.config.audio_encoder.frame_rate + 3
inputs = processor(
    text=input_text,
    padding=True,
    return_tensors="pt",
).to(device)
audio_values = model.generate(
    **inputs,
    max_new_tokens=num_tokens,  # defines the length of the generated music piece
    guidance_scale=g_scale,  # controls the creativity level  # The guidance_scale is used in classifier free guidance...Higher guidance scale encourages the model to generate samples that are more closely linked to the input prompt
    do_sample=True,  # enables stochastic sampling, making the generation process more creative  # sampling leads to significantly better results than greedy (do_sample=False)
)


https://github.com/yy1lab/Lyrics-Conditioned-Neural-Melody-Generation I can't run whether in python 2.7 or newer
https://github.com/lucidrains/musiclm-pytorch it seems models in hubert have errors; in my case, they are


KeyError: 'hubert_pretraining'

with HuBERT Base or

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'task'

with HuBERT Large
any ideals
